# Empty cell when doubleclicking for editing to a cell

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I'm using IBindingList as itemssource.  At first, list is empty. So user have to add new rows, which works fine. While adding new rows, I can set any field to any value i want.And it gets displayed on the grid.

But when it comes to editing cell values, there are no editing controls appear. And the strange thing is you can edit the value, but without seeing what you're doing.

Could this be caused by setting the MaxHeight to something ?

I've tried to add a TextEditSettings :

```
      <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
         <dxe:TextEditSettings Mask="N2" MaskType="Numeric">
         </dxe:TextEditSettings>
      </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
```

But still...

How is this possible? Am i doing something wrong ?

*** Update ***

I've found the hidden numbers :) Appearently they're not gone, its just when editing cell, the control's width (which is used to edit the value), is too much for the column's width. So, thats why i can't see it. I've tried to set view's AutoWidth property to true but stil...

Answer (score 0):

I got it ! It was caused by the global styles.  There were some styles that targeted both dockpanel and textbox editors which caused fixing size of editing control.

So i've removed them everything is fine. Thanks to the DevXpress team...